# Защита от UDP FLOOD

Tags: сеть, udp, ddos

Подскажите пожалуйста, как через fail2ban защитить сервер от UDP FLOOD атак?

Comment: `fail2ban` не защищает от `DOS`-атак. Он защищает от брутфорса пароля. По умолчанию сервер будет отвечать на любую попытку входа. `fail2ban` же после нескольких неудачных попыток банит `ip`, с которого они идут, и сервер просто перестаёт реагировать на них.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Трафик будет литься в независимости от того есть правила на фаерволе или нет.